# Incorrect output with 'while' and variables, in Python game

Tags: python

I have been having issues with running my code as a problem occurs in this section of code within my program. Every time I attempt to 'keep' or 'change' the case, the program simply outputs a blank line.

I prefer to only provide this section of my program, as I feel this is the root of the issue.

```
if (len(remainderCases) == finalRoundRemainder):
    print("Only 2 cases left - the case you chose at the beginning of the game, Case #" + str(user) + ",")
    print("and Case #" + str(remainderCases[0]) + ". The result will be your winnings.")
    keepOrChange = input("Would you like to 'keep' or 'change' your case: ")

    while (keepOrChange != "keep") and (keepOrChange != "change"):
        keepOrChange = input("The value '" + str(keepOrChange) + "' is invalid. Would you like to keep or change your case (enter 'keep' or 'change'): ")
        if (keepOrChange == "keep"):
            print(userValue)

        else:
            print(remainder)
else:
    print("")
    print("Next case!")
```

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: Please don't just remove your code. It is part of the question just as everything else and can help to understand the issue so others can makes sure they have the same/similar issue. If there is anything in your code that should have been kept confidential you can mod-flag your question and explain the issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the indentation. Your while loop is correct, but when you input either 'keep' or 'change' you exit the while loop. I believe that you want to have this instruction checked at that point

```
if (keepOrChange == "keep"):
    print(userValue)
else:
    print(remainder)
```

but from the way you indented it, it can be reached only from inside the while loop, but you enter it only when the variable is not applicable to the if condition.
Remove one indentation for the above block and it should do what you need.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for your help, I was stuck on this issue for quite some time.

Comment: No problem, it's not a big deal. I discovered yesterday that I had a bug in my thesis since a couple of weeks :P